# I need refreshed data from query. Difference between query hints in EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

EclipseLink

I'm using

```
query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");
```

or

```
query.setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH, HintValues.TRUE);
```

What is the difference between these two ways?

Comment: All I see in your question is two lines of code floating with no context. Where do these classes come from ? I did not find any reference to it in the standard library

Comment: I forgote. I'm using EclipseLink and import import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.eclipse.persistence.config.HintValues;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints;<br/><br/> example:   
<br/>
`TypedQuery<Part> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Part.findAll", Part.class);
  <br/>query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");
  <br/>List<Part> list = query.getResultList();`

Comment: Don't comment, edit your answer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javax.persistence.cache.storeMode is documented as a javax.persistence property here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjjj.html

While QueryHints.REFRESH is documented here: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_refresh.htm

Essentially they are the same thing, with the QueryHints.REFRESH predating the JPA query hint standard.  Both will act as if em.refresh was called on each entity returned.